# Read a word (.docx) file in java

Tags: java, spring, docx4j

I have a word document which was generated with docx4j, when i unzip the docx file, the contents of folder is
[image: Contents of .docx folder]

the contents of ./word/document.xml is as  below

[image]

the relationship xml has below relationship

```
<Relationship Target="../chunk.docx" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk" Id="rId3"/>
```

when we unzip chunk.docx it has below file contents

[image]

and the ./word/document.xml has below contents

[image]

relationship document xml has below contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
<Relationship Target="styles.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" Id="rId1"/>
<Relationship Target="settings.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings" Id="rId2"/>
<Relationship Target="../chunk.docx" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk" Id="rId3"/>
<Relationship Target="../chunk2.docx" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk" Id="rId4"/>
<Relationship Target="../chunk3.docx" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk" Id="rId5"/>
<Relationship Target="../chunk4.docx" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk" Id="rId6"/>
<Relationship Target="../chunk5.docx" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk" Id="rId7"/>
```

similarly when i unzip the chunk.docx it has below file contents
[image]

and ./word/document.xml has below contents

[image]

How to read the content of word document via java code

i have tried below way

```
File docxFile = new File(filePath);
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(docxFile);
        MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordprocessingMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
        List<Object> textNodes = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(TEXT_NODEX_XPATH, true);
```

But it is giving 0 textNodes, Can anyone help how can i read this type of word docx using java

Comment: Maybe you should try Apache POI

Comment: I have tried apache POI and that is also not able to read

Comment: Then it is better to join the POI community and help improve that rather than implementing from scratch.

Comment: Does the document load and display properly in MS Word?

Comment: yes, when opened through word its readable but in compatibility mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docx contains altChunks of type docx.

It contains those because that would've been done explicitly when whoever created it did so using docx4j, using code such as https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_11_4_7/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/AltChunkAddOfTypeDocx.java

Ordinarily you wouldn't do that.

Generally, if you want to handle such a docx using approaches like XPath, you'd first convert those altChunks into normal content.  Word can do this, as can Docx4j Enterprise.

But if you control the generating application, the best approach would be to revisit it, changing it so it doesn't create altChunks.  At least understand why they wrote it that way.